# What is the difference between a web service and a web application?

Tags: web-services, web-applications

How can we differentiate between a web service and a web application?

Comment: Interesting question, though it has a 'wiki'-feeling to it. I suggest making it a community wiki for added community enthusiasm. ;)

Comment: Homework or not, I think this is a good question.

Answer (score 11):

There's a variety of answers to this question, but I think the most concise is as follows.  A web application is designed to be used by humans, whereas a web service is designed to be used by other pieces of software (which may or may not be part of a web application).  Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Think of a web service as a function you can call through the internet. In contrast a web application is the whole thing, including gui.

Answer (score 1):

Web application have both UI and data communication functionality.. while web service only meant to transfer data or actions.

Answer (score 1):

One is optimized for computer access, while the other is optimized for human access.